# Distribution of modulo of a prime number versus that of a non-prime.

Tags: number-theory

Given a set of random numbers, and two functions $F(x) = x\,\%\,n$ and $G(x) = x\,\%\,m$ where $n$ is prime and $m$ is not prime, is it the case that the range of $F$ will be "more evenly distributed" than that of $G$?

Answer (score 4):

If the set of random numbers is chosen with uniform distribution on the interval $[1,M]$, where $M$ is large, then $F(x)$ has nearly uniform distribution on $[0,n-1]$ and $G(x)$ has nearly uniform distribution on $[0,m-1]$. Primality is not relevant.